# Extract substrings in a text, on columns using Pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, text-mining

I'm new in python, so.... I have a dataframe like this:

```py
    id   city      name     text
    1    Boston    Rosie    I have some text here, as you can see.
    2    New York  Liza     I love my cat
```

So I'l like to search inside each row the text and have some result like:

I rearch in the text "love" or "love" && "cat" and I want return the city or the name.

I tried the follow code:

```py
   if df[df['text'].str.contains("love") | df['text'].str.contains("cat")]:
    print(df['name'])
```

It's throwing an error of the form "The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Comment: When you say not working, do you mean an error message is popping up? (if yes, what does the error message say). Or is it running fine, just not producing the desired results?

Comment: @Nebulous29 this is the error: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Comment: @HugoB Always include the entire error message. It would have made it easier to tell that there already answers to this question, for one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use boolean index with `pandas.Series.str.contains`:

```
df['name'][df['text'].str.contains("cat|love")]
```

Output:

```
1    Liza
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Comment: you user 'or' here but if I use 'and' (&), it gives me the empty result. Why?

Comment: And if I'd like to add also the 'city' in my result?

Comment: @HugoB Because there is no operator for AND in regex. In that case, you will have to use it `df['name'][df['text'].str.contains("cat") & df['text'].str.contains("love")]`. For the second comment, try `df[['name','city']][...]`